# Angular 4.3.0 & cli 1.2.0: after running command: "ng test" I've got these failures

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

Angular 4.3.0 & cli 1.2.0: after running command: "ng test" I've got these failures

```
    AppComponent should create the app should have as title 'app' should render title in a h1 tag DashboardComponent should be created
```

Comment: I think this is not failures of  your test environment but it is the failure of your test case. You should write a proper test case.

Comment: @ARUN: can you explain???

Comment: @Samil can you share the screenshot of you terminal when running the `ng test`?

Comment: @ARUN: I just run: "ng test"...

Comment: angular-cli: after running this command: "ng build --prod --env=prod" I've got that error:
    ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/home/salim/Development/www/kpittu/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng test` check code depends on your *.spec.ts, so check your `app.component.spec.ts`, find the error message, like

```
it(`should have as title 'app'`, async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  expect(app.title).toEqual('app'); // <--- this line cause the error, it means in your app.component.ts there should has a variable **title** and equal *app*
}));
```